# collectionView didSelectItemAt superview not selecting the correct Object

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a list of sensors in a collectionView inside a UIView class called `MyCropView` where I show some data about that crop.
Im trying to change the value of some sensors like the icon and the background color on each click.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let myCropCard = collectionView.superview as! MyCropCard

    let sensor = myCropCard.sensors[indexPath.row]
    let cell = myCropCard.superview

    //Change the color and icon of the sensors 
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? MyCollectionViewCell {
        //Previous cell in grey
        if !self.lastSelectedIndexPath.isEmpty {
            let lastCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: self.lastSelectedIndexPath) as? MyCollectionViewCell
            lastCell?.imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.95, green: 0.95, blue: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
            lastCell?.imageView.image = UIImage(named: self.lastSelectedImageName )
        }

        //Makes sensor green onSelect
        cell.imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.882, green: 0.95, blue: 0.882, alpha: 1.0)
        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: sensor.getType() )
        self.lastSelectedIndexPath = indexPath
        self.lastSelectedImageName = String(format: "%@_deactivated", sensor.getType())
    }

    //Show all the alerts of each sensor
    for alert:Alert in sensor.getAlerts() {
        let viewSensor = cell?.viewWithTag(300) as! SensorView
        viewSensor.lblSensor.text = sensor.getTipo()
        viewSensor.lblBotLog.text = alerta.getNombreDispositivo()
        viewSensor.lblMin.text = String(format: "MIN %.0f", alert.getMin())
        viewSensor.lblMax.text = String(format: "MAX %.0f", alert.getMax())
        viewSensor.btnDel.tag = Int(alert.getId() + 1000) 
        viewSensor.btnDel.addTarget(
            self,
            action: #selector( viewSensor.deleteAlert(_:) ),
            for: .touchUpInside
        )
        viewSensor.isHidden = false
    }

}
```

That collectionView is the list of sensors we have. It works fine with 1st MyCropCard, But doesn't for multiple MyCropCards. Superview takes the first cropCard of them all, not the collectionView's parent.

I would like to know how can I correctly have the parent of the selected collectionView?

Comment: Do you mean you have multiple `MyCropCard`s, each containing a collectionView?

Comment: Yes, that exactly. And I have multiple other `customTableViewCells` that contain those multiple `MyCropCard`s

Comment: Did you properly set the delegate for all other collectionViews?

Comment: Yes. it actually shows the correct sensors for each card, and it also shows the correct alerts for each sensor.

Comment: "Superview takes the first cropCard of them all, not the collectionView's parent.": are you talking about the `myCropCard` variable?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about that variable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198388/discussion-between-jay-lee-and-jalil).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is cluttered with unneccessary logic-related codes, which are probably unrelated to the issue.
Also, extensive use of `tag`s are making the code unscalable and hard to maintain, so it probably needs a heavy refactoring.

The following code is basically a MWE for what you want to achieve (If I misunderstood your issue, let me know).

To explain the code, this is a custom tableViewCell:

```swift
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
  var collectionView: UICollectionView? {
    didSet {
      guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return }
      contentView.addSubview(collectionView)
      collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
      setupCollectionViewLayout(collectionView)
    }
  }

  private func setupCollectionViewLayout(_ collectionView: UICollectionView) {
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      collectionView.leadingAnchor
        .constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
      collectionView.trailingAnchor
        .constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
      collectionView.topAnchor
        .constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
      collectionView.bottomAnchor
        .constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
    ])
  }
}
```

`setupCollectionViewLayout` simply enables AutoLayout. `collectionView` will be later added when a `tableViewCell` instance is dequeued.

```swift
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  private var lastSelectedCollectionViewCell: CollectionViewCell?

  private lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
    let tableView = UITableView()
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    return tableView
  }()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = .white
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    setupTableViewLayout(tableView)
  }

  private func setupTableViewLayout(_ tableView: UITableView) {
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
      tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
      tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
      tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
    ])
  }
}
```

`tableView` is added as the view is loaded, and AutoLayout constraints are added by `setupTableViewLayout`.
Note that you keep a copy of the last index path, but I think it is better and simpler to keep a reference to the cell itself.

In `UITableViewDataSource` extension:

```swift
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
      withIdentifier: "cell",
      for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    guard cell.collectionView == nil else { return cell }

    let collectionView = UICollectionView(
      frame: .zero,
      collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())

    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    cell.collectionView = collectionView

    return cell
  }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {}
```

I add a `collectionView` *only if* it doesn't already exist in a `tableViewCell`.
`collectionView` assigns `dataSource` and `delegate` as `self`, though it would be better if there is an extra modelController object.
`UITableViewDelegate` is empty.

Now extensions for the `collectionView`s:

```swift
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = .gray
    return cell
  }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    lastSelectedCollectionViewCell?.backgroundColor = .gray
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell {
      cell.backgroundColor = .yellow
      lastSelectedCollectionViewCell = cell
    }
  }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)
  }
}
```

The important part is `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)`, and the others are just boilerplate code.
When a collectionViewCell is selected, the `self.lastSelectedCollectionViewCell`'s color turns back to gray, and the newly selected cell is assigned to `lastSelectedCollectionViewCell`, after its `backgroundColor` changed.

The following is the entire code you can run in Playground:

```swift
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
  var collectionView: UICollectionView? {
    didSet {
      guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return }
      contentView.addSubview(collectionView)
      collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
      setupCollectionViewLayout(collectionView)
    }
  }

  private func setupCollectionViewLayout(_ collectionView: UICollectionView) {
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      collectionView.leadingAnchor
        .constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
      collectionView.trailingAnchor
        .constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
      collectionView.topAnchor
        .constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
      collectionView.bottomAnchor
        .constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
    ])
  }
}

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  private var lastSelectedCollectionViewCell: CollectionViewCell?

  private lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
    let tableView = UITableView()
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    return tableView
  }()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = .white
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    setupTableViewLayout(tableView)
  }

  private func setupTableViewLayout(_ tableView: UITableView) {
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
      tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
      tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
      tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
    ])
  }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
      withIdentifier: "cell",
      for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    guard cell.collectionView == nil else { return cell }

    let collectionView = UICollectionView(
      frame: .zero,
      collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())

    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    cell.collectionView = collectionView

    return cell
  }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = .gray
    return cell
  }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    lastSelectedCollectionViewCell?.backgroundColor = .gray
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell {
      cell.backgroundColor = .yellow
      lastSelectedCollectionViewCell = cell
    }
  }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)
  }
}


PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

Comment: Thank you. now the code is working. But the autoresizing is not actually working.

Comment: @Jalil To make autolayout work, remove the sizeForItemAt delegate method *entirely* and put constraints.